# My telegram bots stopped working

Tags: php, bots, host, webhooks, telegram

I have two bots on my server but since 4 days ago both of them stopped working.
I checked the script on the other server and I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with it. also I talked to my hosting provider and seems that there is nothing wrong with it too.

What's going wrong?

Update : "I'm using webhooks"

Comment: So if there is no errors or something, we can't help you at all. Sorry, but we're not wizards who can guess how your code / server looks like.

Comment: more details => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448889/how-to-use-a-particular-port-to-send-or-get-updates-via-webhook-to-telegram

Answer (score 0):

When sending messages inside a particular chat, avoid sending more than one message per second. We may allow short bursts that go over this limit, but eventually you'll begin receiving 429 errors.

If you're sending bulk notifications to multiple users, the API will not allow more than 30 messages per second or so. Consider spreading out notifications over large intervals of 8—12 hours for best results.

Also note that your bot will not be able to send more than 20 messages per minute to the same group.